# Broken links in head of wordpress site after host change and moved to different directory

Tags: wordpress

Wanted to move my WordPress installation from my local development setup to my host.

On my local development, I had it installed in a `./wordpress subfolder`. then I copied the contents to the root of my host. I updated the wp-config.php. Database connection works I updated also the URLs in the wp_options table.

Using PHPMyAdmin I replaced all the old URLs occurring in the tables wp_posts, wp_options and wp_postmeta with the new URL.

Now I get still some linking errors for stylesheets, js resources, and also images. As seen in this screenshot there is still sometimes `"/wordress/"` in the url.

[image: GET Errors as shown in Chrome]

Seems like I need to get rid of this "WordPress" string in the URL.

I searched the whole database for `"WordPress" "/wordpress", "/wordpress/",` `"info/wordpress" "wordpress/wp-"` and I can't find any entries that could cause this.

I also used grep to search through all the file contents if there are any URLs specified like that.

Is there something obvious that I missed?

Comment: You did something wrong with the search and replace. Re-upload your database and run this tool https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: ok, will try, still would like to know why this happened..

Comment: found this in wp-config.php

`if ($_SERVER["HOST"] != "") {
 define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL);
} else {
        define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL.'/wordpress');
}`

removed the "wordpress" now it looks like it works. Is this safe or just a dirty hack?

`if ($_SERVER["HOST"] != "") {
 define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL);
} else {
        define('WP_SITEURL', $pageURL.'/');
}`

Comment: This local wordpress installation was done with the synology package manager maybe thats why it was hardcoded like that?

Comment: No the problem is that you are doing it manually. It's easy to overlook something. The `wp-config.php` part defining the location is not needed and manually added. If you use the default installation sequence WordPress provides these aren't added.

Comment: You might want to reinstall WordPress from scratch to be sure. Download a fresh copy and install that. Make sure you got a backup from your database and `plugins, themes and upload` folders so you can restore them after the installation of WordPress